# Python - Pick_Event for pcolor get pandas column and index value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to to create a pick_event for pcolor which is working fine so far. however, I would like to get the column and index name of the underlying pandas DataFrame.
With event.ind I just get one value which seems to be counted with ignoring nan values.

Eventually I would like to use the column and index name to return a value from another pandas DataFrame with the same index and column values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import matplotlib as mpl

class colormap:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,12).reshape(3,4), index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=float)
        data.set_value('a', 'B', np.nan)
        data = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(data), data)

        ax.pcolor(data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=0.2, cmap='RdBu', picker=1)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)
        plt.show()

    def onpick(self, event):
        self.event = event
        self.thisline = event.artist
        ind = event.ind
        print(ind)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    self = colormap()
    self.create()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to work with a non masked array. This will throw a warning, but still works, if you set the colorlimits in `pcolor` using `vmin` and `vmax`. In order for the nan value to become transparent one needs to set the `colormap.set_under(color)` to a transparent color.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

class colormap:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create(self):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,12).reshape(3,4), index=['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                            columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=float)
        self.data.set_value('a', 'B', np.nan)
        #data = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(data), data)
        cmap = plt.cm.RdBu
        cmap.set_under((0,0,0,0))
        ax.pcolor(self.data, edgecolors='k', linewidths=0.2, cmap=cmap, picker=1, 
                  vmin=0, vmax=11)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)
        plt.show()

    def onpick(self, event):
        self.event = event
        self.thisline = event.artist
        ind = event.ind
        x,y = np.unravel_index(ind, self.data.shape)
        x,y = x[0],y[0]
        print (x,y, self.data.iloc[x,y])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    self = colormap()
    self.create()
```

In this way the return `(n,m, self.data.iloc[n,m])` is the `(row, column, data[row,column])`.

Comment: Thanks, that's already coming closer to the solution. I'm still struggling with the part how to get the index and column value for the selected datapoint.

Comment: I have a question here: Do you always plot the pcolor on the index scale or would you eventually like to use a different scaling (i.e. at the moment the axes go from 0 to 3 or 4, would they use a different scaling afterwards?).

Comment: The scale would eventually change depending on the dataset

Comment: of course I can nnow use this index to convert it back to a 'x & y' value. I'm just wondering if there is a more direct way. Otherwise I guess that would already do the job

Comment: I edited the answer to directly give the 2 dimensional index. I think if you may change the scale afterwards this is the best solution.

Comment: Thx, just received enough point to actually do upvotes :) Thanks again